# How to make local repositories not track changes on a file that must remain present on the remote repository

Tags: git, bitbucket, gitignore

I work for a company where we must make branches of the master branch, make changes and then merge, however, every time someone has to create a branch to add a new feature there is a couple of files that they must modify to fit their local setups, and when you push to the remote repository of your  personal branch you are really not suposed to allow the changes made to those specific files reach the remote, the remote files must remain unchanged.

To clarify because i'm a noob and idk if i've explained what i want to happen correctly

Create branch form master > modify as much as i want on local including the specific files > push all changes but the changes to the specific files are ignored whan pushed > the specific files must remain on their default state and still exist on the branch remote.

I've though of simply adding the files to the gitignore but this i believe will make the original files not be on the remote repository.

I know that i can do something like this by adding to the gitignore but then have to make a couple of commands on terminal i'm not too sure of to untrack the files, but i'd like that the files are dowloaded to the local branch any changes are ignored by default.

If it's relevant the software we use for this stuff is bitbucket for remote and IDEA intellij Community edition. I apologize if the question is worded weird, english is not my first language and i'm not very knowledgeable on Git in general

Comment: `git help update-index`, specifically, `--assume-unchanged`.

Comment: @eftshift0 `--assume-unchanged` has another purpose. Use `--skip-worktree` instead :P

Comment: @miro `.gitignore` has no effect on tracked files.

Comment: Can't mark the answer as correct with this kind of comment, but `git update-index --assume-unchanged` and `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged` to undo did what i wanted. Have to undo it to switch branches tho.